# Problems using IMPORTXML

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to use the IMPORTXML formula on Google sheet in order to import data available on "https://www.bloomberg.com/markets/stocks", in the section "Asia Pacific".
The following code seems not to work:

```
=IMPORTXML("https://www.bloomberg.com/markets/stocks", "//table[@class='data-table']")
```

I want to retrieve the "% change" of the Asia Pacific indexes

Answer (score 0):

That URL does not appear to be providing information in XML format—try utilizing the `=IMPORTHTML()` function